# Background image is not showing in GitHub pages

Tags: css, sass, github-pages

My svgs as `background-image` or even `background` is not showing up in GitHub pages. They seem to be working locally though. I used sass as a preprocessor for css, if that's relevant.

Can anyone help me debug this. Your help would be appreciated!

[Project link](https://arkharman12.github.io/faq-accordion-card/)

[Github repo](https://github.com/arkharman12/faq-accordion-card)

Comment: Your paths are absolute, but they must be relative to the base-url (`https://arkharman12.github.io/faq-accordion-card`). So change your image paths in your style.css from `url("/images/....svg")` to `url("./images/....svg")`. You can see the 404 requests in the developer tool of your browser.

Comment: @SvenEberth Still no luck. Please check the repo now?!

Comment: My bad. Must be `url("../images/....svg")`

Comment: Ahhh yeah, thanks! Silly mistake :D

Answer (score 0):

your background-image must look like this.

background-image: url(../images/pattern-hills.svg), not that

background-image: url("/images/pattern-hills.svg"),